# Programming mouse buttons 6-9

Tags: mouse, key-bindings, hotkeys

My Zelotes F-15 9 button mouse has just arrived, and to my horror I've realised it has come without any native button rebinding software.
There are plenty of third party apps that'll rebind buttons 1-5, however I also need mousekeys 6, 7, 8 and 9 programmed.

I can switch the mouse to multimedia mode which turns buttons 5-9 into win, esc, space, left, right. I can easily rebind these keys using something like autohotkey but the problem is that I still need the use of those keys on the keyboard.

My understanding is that I need to mess with mouse drivers and/or registry keys to get this level of customisation.

Would somebody be able to shed some light on this for me?

I can't seem to find any downloadable drivers, I can provide Hardware ID's if that helps.

Thanks in advance

ES

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a very old question, but I too had this problem as I wanted to be able to program my HOME key for use in games. I figured out that the home key presses Windows+D by default which goes to desktop. Disabling that with autohotkey I tried to play but since I use WASD to move it would keep pressing Windows+W or Windows+A which would open up Workspace or Action Center. I disabled those hotkeys too and finally came up with this code for Autohotkey which works like a dream:

```
#NoEnv ;
; #Warn ;
SendMode Input ;
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% ;
#MenuMaskKey vk07
#d::return
#w::return
#a::return
#s::return
```

This successfully maps the HOME button to the Windows button without making the start menu or anything else come up so you can program it in your games